# Twilio Studio Send and Wait for Reply at the end of a call

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

We have a flow where we want the user to call and record things. At the end we send them a text message and gather their response with a Send and Wait Widget. After their response, we want to have a POST function that runs.

This POST function works when people are just texting but it isn't working from the Send and Wait function at the end of the call.

We understand that Send and Waits don't work properly later in flows as they are read as initial texts -- but does this also mean they can't collect message bodies?

Thanks! :)

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue you encountered. For the Send and Wait Widget when processing an inbound call, did you disable the concurrent calls trigger (and understand its impact)?

Comment: I forgot to respond when this happened but this did work!